# select columns by a concat text as columnname in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a table with columns named with the number of hour of day like this:

```
col00 NUMBER(5)
col01 NUMBER(5)
col02 NUMBER(5)
...
col23 NUMBER(5)
```

...and I have another query that returns a count by hour.

I want to recover the colXX value by hour.... then I can recover with "decode" or "case when..." but I want know if exists any way to recover the column by a text like this:

```
select "col"||hour from table;
```

in the hypothetical above example if hour is 13 then would be translated like:

```
select col13 from table;
```

there is any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing...

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(
 REGEXP_REPLACE( DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('
 SELECT col'|| to_char(sysdate,'HH24') || ' FROM TABLE
'),'.*<[/]?(\?xml .*>|ROW).*',''),'  (<([^>]*)>([^<]*)</[^>]*>.*)','\2=\3') AS RES  from dual
```

its not so simple but very flexible and works great for me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col'|| hour || ' FROM TABLE;'
```

Reference:

- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE option for Dynamic SQL and PL/SQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2109681/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-option-for-Dynamic-SQL-and-PLSQL.htm)

Comment: I know the execute immediate but i need it in a subquery. NOT a PL block.

Comment: @glaudiston: You can't - either the entire query is dynamic SQL, or you make a function (or stored procedure) to return the value based on this dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

While it looks a little...brute force...you could use a bunch of UNION statements between queries:

```
SELECT col00
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') = '00'
UNION
SELECT col01
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') = '01'
UNION
SELECT col02
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') = '02'  
   (...and so on...)
UNION
SELECT col23
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') = '23'
```

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for... but thks anyway.

Comment: thanks for response, but i found a way more flexible with dbms_xml.getxml('query'). in this way I can generate the query and get its result.

Comment: select dbms_xml.getxml('SELECT col'|| to_char(sysdate,'HH24') || ' FROM TABLE;') from dual;